# How to show json data in laravel

Tags: laravel

i have json array from `return $data->group`, here the result:

```
[{
"id": 2,
"name": "Grup 1",
"created_at": "2016-03-16 02:09:15",
"updated_at": "2016-03-16 02:09:15",
"pivot": {
    "cabang_id": 28,
    "group_id": 2
}}]
```

i want to "id" and "name" from this data.

i have tried using `$data->group->id` and `$data->group->name` but error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id`

how can i take from `$data->group`?

Comment: Could you please provide what you've done so far? Your question is rather hard to answer as it contains very little detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
```

Then it shows that you're dealing with a `Collection` object. You can access a `Collection`'s attribute's using the `get('key')` method as user Alexy Mezenin mentioned.

So you would do something like this in your case:

```
$data->group->get('id')
```

Check the docs/api for further details:

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-get

Api: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_get

Normally you can make use of an [Eloquent model's magic methods](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method___get) to access its attributes directly by their key name as you were trying to do in the code sample you gave, i.e. `$data->group->id`. I believe this isn't working for you because you've already returned the data as json, if you would access the object before returning it as json then you would probably be able to access the attributes using the magic methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `->get('id')` on the object with json data. Or `$request->input('id')` where `$request` is your `Request` object.